# Wildfly: Receiving shutdown event to prevent early shutdown of ManagedExecutorService

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I'm using ManagedExecutorService in my app, specifically with Quartz. Its watcher threads are run within the executor service.

At app shutdown I stop Quartz in a @PreDestroy method and it should finish its watcher threads - that's what how it's meant to be and how it have been until I switched to managed executor.

The problem now is that when I shutdown the server, ManagedExecutorService shuts down before @PreDestroy gets called.

Is there a way I can get a notification of a shutdown event? Can I declare some kind of dependency on "ManagedExecutors subsystem" so that it gets cleaned up when "CDI subsystem" is finished?

Comment: Why are you using Quartz in a JEE environment?  A @ Schedule Singleton would allow for a PreDestroy and you'd likely make your code much simpler too.

Comment: What kind of bean has the `@PreDestroy` method?

Comment: @stdunbar perhaps, it is more agile and more featured. is been here for a while and it was not me who brought it into the app.

Comment: @SteveC it is javax.ejb.Singleton , but `@Resource` is injected in a different place. should try injecting it to the `@PreDestroy` bean also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, I should have declared `@Resource ManagedExecutorService` in the class thats is dependent on managed executor to prevent its early shutdown.